# Multiple providers and Router in React hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-hooks, react-router-dom

I'm using multiple contexts and reducers in React hooks.

This is my App.js file

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

import Map from "./components/Map";
import Header from "./components/Header";
import Signup from "./components/Auth/Signup";
import Login from "./components/Auth/Login";
import UserList from "./components/User/UserList";

import "mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.css";

import { ApolloProvider } from "react-apollo";
import { ApolloClient } from "apollo-client";
import { WebSocketLink } from "apollo-link-ws";
import { InMemoryCache } from "apollo-cache-inmemory";
import { default as keysConfig } from "./keys.config";
import AuthProvider from "./providers/authProvider";
import withRoot from "./providers/withRoot";
import PageContent from "./pages/pageContent";
import ProtectedRoute from "./routePermissions/ProtectedRoute";
import AdminRoute from "./routePermissions/AdminRoute";
import PinProvider from "./providers/pinProvider";
import UserProvider from "./providers/userProvider";

const wsLink = new WebSocketLink({
  uri: `${keysConfig.WssBaseUrl}/graphql`,
  options: {
    reconnect: true
  }
});

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: wsLink,
  cache: new InMemoryCache()
});

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <ApolloProvider client={client}>
        <AuthProvider>
          <PageContent>
            <Header />
            <Switch>
              <PinProvider>
                <ProtectedRoute exact path="/" component={Map} />
              </PinProvider>
              <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
              <Route exact path="/signup" component={Signup} />
              <UserProvider>
                <AdminRoute exact path="/userlist" component={UserList} />
              </UserProvider>
            </Switch>
          </PageContent>
        </AuthProvider>
      </ApolloProvider>
    </Router>
  );
};

export default withRoot(App);
```

I'm using multiple contexts and reducers. It makes me use multiple providers. But I'd like to use the provider to the specific route.

When I use the Route like the code snippet, ProtectedRoute is not working.

I hope someone help me to solve this issue.
You can provide me the good way how to combine the multiple contexts and reducers in react hooks more efficiently.

Comment: What exactly is not working? Why dont you just put the provider inside the specific round? `UserProvder` could be put inside `AdminRoute` for example, since only `AdminRoute` is using it?

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I would appreciate it if you would provide me how to put the User provider inside the AdminRoute?

Comment: @skyboyer already showed you an example. Thats what I meant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[UPD] Beware, question was asked and answer has been given in time of React Router 5. For v6 [it's not longer allowed](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5#refactor-custom-routes) to have something except `<Route>` as a child of `<Switch>`

`<Switch>` operates on first level children. It does not care if it's `<Route>` or `<Provider>`. So you need to adjust your code moving providers inside components or just utilizing `render()` variant of `Route`:

```
<Switch>
  <ProtectedRoute 
    exact 
    path="/" 
    render={(...params) => 
      <PinProvider><Map {...params} /></PinProvider>
    } 
  />
  <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
  <Route exact path="/signup" component={Signup} />
  <AdminRoute 
    exact 
    path="/userlist" 
    render={(params) => 
      <UserProvider><UserList {...params} /></UserProvider>
    } 
  />
</Switch>
```

should work fine